# What is the intuition behind the definiton of a seperable field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, separable-extension

so I am currently studying separable extensions in John Fraleigh's abstract algebra book and have come upon this definiton of a separable field extension:

> A finite extension $E$ of $F$ is a **separable extension of** $F$ if $\{E:F\}=[E:F]$. An element $\alpha$ of $\overline{F}$ is **separable over** $F$ if $F(\alpha)$ is a seperable extension of $F$. An irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is **separable over** $F$ if every zero of $f(x)$ in $\overline{F}$ is separable over $F$.

I understand that this definition then leads us to study the multiplicity of the zeros of $\text{irr}(\alpha, F)$ and that an extension is only separable if the multiplicity of the zeros in $\overline{F}[x]$ is equal to one. However, I don't understand why this would lead us to call the extension separable. In my mind when I think of something that is separable I think of decomposing the structure in one way or another. Is there a way to think about seperable extensions in this manner, or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: You can prove that that a field extension $E/F$ of degree $n\geq 1$  is separable if and only if $E\otimes_F \bar{F}\simeq \bar{F}^n$

Maybe this is the kind of result you're looking for ?

Comment: @GreginGre I am sorry, but I am not entirely sure what the equation means. Could you try to explain in words?